# Managing channels in portaudio

Tags: c, audio, portaudio

Currently working on a realtime sound application in C, I am learning how to use `portaudio`.

My first problem is that I don't really understand how to manage channels.
Let admit that I want to only pass audio through `portaudio`.
I think that my callback function would be :

```
static int fuzzCallback( const  void *inputBuffer,
                            void *outputBuffer,
                            unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                            const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                            PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                            void *userData )
{
    SAMPLE *out = (SAMPLE*)outputBuffer;
    const SAMPLE *in = (const SAMPLE*)inputBuffer;
    (void) timeInfo; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
    (void) statusFlags;
    (void) userData;

    *out++ = *in++; // Left channel
    *out++ = *in++; // Right channel

    return paContinue;
}
```

Let now admit that I want to switch my inputs and send it to my output, namely sending `input 1` to `output 2` and `input 2` to `output 1`.

How would I achieve that by using `portaudio`? I expect something like `*out.1++ = *in.2++;` but can't find any information about this.

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`out` and `in` are arrays of `float` where the channels are interleaved. Meaning `in` is L1,R1,L2,R2,L3,R3... Same on the output. To swap the channels change the indexing around when you are copying from the input to the output.

```
static int fuzzCallback( const  void *inputBuffer,
                         void *outputBuffer,
                         unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                         const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                         PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                         void *userData )
{
    SAMPLE *out = (SAMPLE*)outputBuffer;
    const SAMPLE *in = (const SAMPLE*)inputBuffer;
    (void) timeInfo; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
    (void) statusFlags;
    (void) userData;


    for (int i=0; i < framesPerBuffer; i++)
    {
        out[i*2+1] = in[i*2];   // Left  -> Right
        out[i*2]   = in[i*2+1]; // Right -> Left
    }
    return paContinue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you quick answer! It seems to work for now!